# Android Development: compile weird thing

Tags: android

this is the log on a specific project:
[2010-11-29 18:18:39 - A_world] Uploading A_world.apk onto device 'HT057PL10308'
[2010-11-29 18:18:39 - A_world] Installing A_world.apk...
[2010-11-29 18:18:44 - A_world] Success!
[2010-11-29 18:18:44 - A_world] \A_world\bin\A_world.apk installed on device
[2010-11-29 18:18:44 - A_world] Done!

on every project except this one it will compile and open the project on the phone but this do nothing on my phone and i cant find the app on my phone. (this failure is only on this project)

why isnt the app installed or open on the phone (on this specific proj)?

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you specify CATEGORY_LAUNCHER (so that is appears in launcher) or CATEGORY_DEFAULT in the manifest for any activity?